# List View performance after notifyDataSetChanged() on HTC One OS 4.3 is very slow

Tags: android, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I have a list view and onItemClick I have to refresh the list with changing the text color of the title of the row. It is working fine on all other devices except HTC One. Below is the code snippet:

```
// Part of Framgent which extends BaseFragment which extends RoboSherlockFragment
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3) {
                Log.e("Cuurent Time setOnItemClickListener", ""+ new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date()));
                onItemClicked(position,adapter);
            }

        });

private void onItemClicked(int position, ArrayAdapter<FollowUpAction> adapter){
    MyApplication.logger.log(Level.INFO,"Type: "+ adapter.getItem(position).getType() + "--");
    FollowUpAction selectedItem = adapter.getItem(position);
    if () 
    {
    }
    else if () 
    {
    } else {
       // this condition gets called
        if(adapter instanceof FollowUpListActionAdapter){
            ((FollowUpListActionAdapter) adapter).onClickOperation(position);;
        }else{
            ((FollowUpActionAdapter) adapter).onClickOperation(position);;
        }
    }
}

public void onClickOperation(int position) {
    int index = isAlreadSelected(position);
    if (index == -1) {
        selected.add(data.get(position));
        DataHolder.getInstance().updateSelectedFollowUpActionList(data.get(position));
    } else {
        selected.remove(index);
        DataHolder.getInstance().removeFromFollowoupActionList(data.get(position));
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.e("Cuurent Time getView for positon", position+"::::"+ new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date()));
    ViewHolderItem viewHolder;
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null) 
    {
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.topics_item_layout, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
        viewHolder.textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.topicItemTextView);
        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.topicsItemImageView);
        row.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else 
    {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) row.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.textView.setText(data.get(position).getLabel().toString());
    if (data.get(position).getChildren() != null&& data.get(position).getChildren().size() > 0) 
    {
        viewHolder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (isAlreadSelected(position) != -1) 
        {
            viewHolder.textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.appGreenColor));
            viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_arrow);
        } else 
        {
            viewHolder.textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.appGrayColor));
            viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.light_gray_select_field_arrow_rotated);
        }
    } else 
    {
        viewHolder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (isAlreadSelected(position) != -1) 
        {
            viewHolder.textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.appGreenColor));
        } else 
        {
            viewHolder.textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.appGrayColor));
        }
    }
    return row;
}
```

Above is the code which is used in this case. If I change this fragment to a separate Activity it starts working fine.

Please help me in this regards.

Comment: Have you tested this on other devices? How is the performance on an emulator?

Comment: I have tested it on Samsung S3 (4.3) and Samsung S4 (4.4) and it is working fine on those devices

Comment: Then, most probably it is a bug in that HTC customized build of Android and as such you can either choose to ignore it or use a separate activity as you've mentioned but take care to ensure that it doesn't alter the behaviour in other devices.

Comment: This is not the case. I have drilled down a bit and found that if I am using the same drawable resource as fragment layout background which has been rendered on the parent activity background of the fragment it works fine but If I use a new drawable its performance starts retarding and annoying

Comment: Can any one help me know how can I resolve this issue. Especially @Ed_Fernando